# Is the state preserved between samples for one batch in a stateful LSTM in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, lstm

Assume I want to classify time series, each of them has 33 time steps. I splitted them up into smaller chunks.
So let's say I have the following Input `X_1`, the dimension is `(32,3,1)`, so 32 samples, 3 time steps, 1 feature:

```
[
    [[1],  [2],  [3]]  # step 1 to step 3 from time series 1
    [[11], [14], [17]] # step 1 to step 3 from time series 2
    [[3],  [5],  [7]]  # step 1 to step 3 from time series 3
    ...
    [[9],  [7],  [2]]  # step 1 to step 3 from time series 32
]
```

and `Y = [A, A, B, …, B]` containing the labels for each of he 32 time series in this batch.

Now I run `model.fit(X_1, Y)`.

Then I take the next 3 time steps for each time series as `X_2`:

```
[
    [[4],  [5],  [6]]  # step 4 to step 6 from time series 1
    [[20], [23], [26]] # step 4 to step 6 from time series 2
    [[9],  [11], [13]] # step 4 to step 6 from time series 3
    ...
    [[8],  [1],  [9]]  # step 4 to step 6 from time series 32
]
```

and again the same `Y = [A, A, B, …, B]`.

Because I've splitted the time series up I use the stateful model, so that the state from `X_1` is being saved for `X_2`.

Again I run `model.fit(X_2, Y)`. I repeat this until I reach `X_11` containing time step 31 to 33 from my input data. After I called `model.fit(X_11, y)` I'm gonna call `model.reset_states()` because I'm done with the first batch of 32 time series, and I can start again at the beginning with a new batch of 32 time series.

At least until now I thought that this is the way to do this. But now I read, that the state is preserved by default across samples in a batch, so does that means that the state from the first 3 steps of time series 1 in `X_0` is also used for the first 3 steps from time series 2? Because that wouldn't make sense, they have nothing in common, the state shouldn't be shared across them. So what is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, states are matrices whose one of the dimensions is the batch size, meaning there is one row of states per sample.

Series 1 does not communicate with series 2.

Comment: Thanks, and that is the reason why the batch size is fixed when using a stateful LSTM, right?

Comment: If you remember that batch1 is communicating with batch2, yes, that's the reason. (The states are flexible to have any batch size, but when you want two batches to share states, then these batches must match)